# Regex expression "\\u002E[^\x5C]*$" not working in C#

Tags: c#, regex, directory, filepath

I'm working on a WPF program in C# that allows for manual entry of a directory path.  My users are not experienced computer users, and are likely to input a file path instead of a path to a directory.

I've created a regular expression that works on the RegExr website EXACTLY how I want, but fails in my C# code.  It triggers whenever a file extension is present at the end of the path the user inputs.  The expression is as follows:

> \x2e[^\x5c]*$

I've tried using this in

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void ConvertFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex rx = new Regex("\u002E[^\x5C]*$");
    }
}
```

I expect the function to work as intended, but instead I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'parsing ".[^]*$" - Unterminated [] set.'

The set of brackets appears to be terminated as far as I can tell, and I don't see anything wrong with this, but it still doesn't work.  I've tried adding and removing the extra backslash, using Unicode `.` and `\`, regular `.` and `\` with escape characters before them, breaking the string into multiple parts, and replacing the `[]` with `()`.  Nothing seems to work and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Either escape the backslash, e.g. "\\u002E[^\x5C]*$" or use the literal operator @, e.g. @"\u002E[^\x5C]*$"

Comment: @RamblinRose: He needs to escape **both** backslashes, not just the first one.

Comment: @BenVoigt indeed, good eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Regex rx = new Regex(@"\u002E[^\x5C]*$");`. The `@` before the string tells the system to interpret every character literally. If there are any characters that you would like to use C#'s escape sequences for (and not those specific to regex!) you should be able to split the string into multiple and concatenate it with `+`.

Comment: The @ worked!  Thanks so much, this had been bugging me all day!

Comment: Glad to help! As a quick note, you can mark answers to your questions as "Accepted" by hitting the checkmark next to them. That signifies that the original issue has been resolved to your liking.

Comment: Awesome, just checked your answer.  Hopefully this'll help someone else out down the line too.

Answer (score 0):

This string:

```
"\u002E[^\x5C]*$"
```

is converted by the compiler to this string:

```
".[^\]*$"
```

The escape codes are processed by the compiler, not the regex engine.

Your attempt at escaping:

```
"\\u002E[^\x5C]*$"
```

generated this string

```
"\u002E[^\]*$"
```

which still allows the regex engine to see `\]` (escaped backslash) instead of a negated character class consisting of backslash.

Disabling compiler interpretation of escape codes with the `@` prefix will work, as will escaping *every* backslash:

```
"\\u002E[^\\x5C]*$"
```

May I remind you that Windows also treats forward slash as a valid directory separator, for example

```
C:/Users/.default/.profile/
```

is a valid name for a directory.

Finally, instead of pattern matching the name, why not just see if the exact name entered by the user exists and whether it is a directory or file?  Because this can also be the name of a directory:

```
C:\Users\.default\.profile
```